# Mahalanobis distance

Tags: metric-spaces, mahalanobis-distance

Suppose there is a function $f$, for which we know the inequality

$$f(r)\leq r$$ 
is true, where $r=||x-y||_2=\sqrt{(x-y)^T (x-y)}$ is the Euclidean distance. If now we use the Mahalanobis distance $r_M=\sqrt{(x-y)^T M^{-1} (x-y)}$, where M is a symmetric positive definite matrix, is the relation

$$f(r_M)\leq r_M$$
still true in general?

Comment: Note that the relation $f(r) \le r$ only depends on the Euclidean norm/distance for the range of values $r$ to which it applies, i.e. all nonnegative real numbers (assuming $x,y$ are allowed to vary without restriction over some Euclidean space).  Then the proposition that $f(r_M) \le r_M$ is similarly not dependent on what measure of distance is involved, but results from the previous claim.

Comment: @hardmath So, does this imply that properties of $f$ that are only dependent on $r$ (e.g. Lipschitz continuity) are true for all metrics?